# how to create a nested dict from a list of tuples?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

So I have this code:

```py
import numpy as np

tempo_de_volta = np.loadtxt('tempos.txt', dtype = float)

carros = np.loadtxt('carros.txt')

tempo_de_volta_hrs = tempo_de_volta / 60

velocidade_media = 20.8 / tempo_de_volta_hrs

velocidade_media = np.round(velocidade_media, 3)

dict1 = dict(list(zip(['tempo']*len(tempo_de_volta), tempo_de_volta)))
```

The problem is here, when I try to create a dict with all the values it only returns the last one, with 'dict1' and 'dict2':

> EX - INPUT :dict2 = dict(list(zip(['velocidade média (km/h)'] * len(velocidade_media), velocidade_media)))

> OUTPUT: {'velocidade média (km/h)': 194.0}

How can I create something like this?:

> classif = {'car1' : {'tempo':7, 'velocidade':100}
> 'car2' : {'tempo':x, 'velocidade':y}
> .
> .
> .
> 'carn': {'tempo':xn, 'velocidade':yn}
> }

Comment: Please provide some sample inputs and their respective outputs you want as well.

Comment: I have three separate inputs, three lists with cars names, their lap times e median velocity, I want to creat a dict relating the car's name with ther timelap and velocity as values, like this: 

classif = {'corvette z06': {'time': 7, 'velocity':120}}

but with the 31 cars on the list, not only the last one

Comment: Your keys are always the same: `['velocidade média (km/h)'] * len(velocidade_media)`. Do a list comprehension there: `["v_{i}".format(i) for i in range(len(velocidade_media))]`

Comment: Where should I put this expression?